# Problem iterating through MySQL in python

Tags: python, mysql

I just started learning python and am trying out projects. I'm having a with my python code. What I want to do is to go through the rows in my table one after another and perform a specific task on each row.
With an example, I have rows with multiple columns and three of the columns are **con_access, exam** and **total.** Now I want to get sum of the values in **con_access** and **exam** columns and then put it in the total column. This calculation should done one by one.
The problem that am having is that the program goes to the last row, takes the total variable and populate every other with it

Below is my code

```
def result_total():
    mdb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="**************",
        database="majesty"
    )

    mycursor = mdb.cursor()
    # mycursor.execute("SELECT con_access, exam FROM students")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT CAST(con_access AS UNSIGNED) as con_access, CAST(exam AS UNSIGNED) as exam FROM students")
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        if row:
            total = row['con_access'] + row['exam']
            sql = "UPDATE students SET total = {}".format(total)
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            mdb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

find total like below

```
total = row['con_access'] + row['exam']
```

If your datatype of con_access and exam in mysql table is varchar, you should cast it. Change the select query as follows.

```sql
SELECT CAST(con_access AS UNSIGNED) as con_access, CAST(exam AS UNSIGNED) as exam FROM students
```

Comment: I got an error saying **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: That means you are storing the values in mysql tables as text. In that case you can use `cast` method in mysql.

Comment: Which is the best way to store the data?  And can you give me example of how to use cast. Still new to these stuffs

Comment: I had edited my answer, with cast in select. Please try it.

Comment: I still get the same error. I've edited the code I posted earlier, help me and check for errors